# How to replace "\n" with "br" in a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML textinput, which I store into a string. I then perform changes to the string and print the result out in a div block next to the input field. However, user input marks newlines as "\n", and innerHTML marks newlines as "<br>". The methods of converting one into the other I tried so far didn't work.

Method 1:
During the transforming process I temporarily perform `s = s.split('');`, then iterate through the whole string to perform changes. I tried doing `if (s[i] == '\n') s[i] = '<br>'`, but it didn't detect the newlines.

Method 2:
After joining the string back, I tried to use RegEx: `s = s.replace("/\n/g", "<br>"`. The result was the same - it didn't detect the newlines.

This code shows my problem:

```
let test = "da\nda"
console.log(test);
test = test.replace("/\n/g", "<br>");
console.log(test);
```

Expected output:

```
da
da
da<br>da
```

Actual output:

```
da
da
da
da
```

Comment: '\n' is special, you need to enable the equivalent of "DOTALL" (/s in recent JavaScript) that is supported by your Regex Engine

Comment: You shoud likely use the <pre> tag or the `white-space: pre-wrap/pre-line` css property instead of trying to convert newlines to <br>. Is there a specific reason you are trying to do it this way? Converting the characters seems like the wrong way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: aside from my previous comment, it seems that the regex should work even without "DOTALL" (at least it does on my browsers), but the "bug" is that the output should go to a different variable to be effective.  Agree though that doing text transormation seems like the wrong approach if the intention is to output it back into the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"da\nda".replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
```

Remove the quotes from your regex.

Answer (score 3):

A single solution for this case

```js
test = test.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");

// using replaceAll
test = test.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these methods can solve your problem

```js
let test = "da\nda";
console.log(test);
test = test.split('\n').join('<br>');
console.log(test);
```

```js
let test = "da\nda";
console.log(test);
test = test.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
console.log(test);
```